# Always On Failover Cluster Instances (FCI) on existing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, clustering, windows-server, sql-server-2019, failover

I have launched three EC2 Windows_Server-2019_SQL_2019_Standard instances. How can I implement Always On Failover Cluster Instances (FCI) on these existing SQL Servers. I can only find details like when you install SQL first time that time only you can choose the Failover Clustering option.

Note: I have already created WSFC Cluster using these three nodes.

Comment: Yes I have created WSFC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert an existing standalone instance to an Failover Clustered Instance (FCI).

You can configure standalone instances to be part of an Availability Group, but FCIs use a separate install path, and must be configured from the point of install.

From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/migration-sql-server/ec2-fci.html)

> FCIs require some form of shared storage—disks on a storage area network (SAN), file shares on Server Message Blocks (SMBs), or locally attached storage with Storage Spaces Direct (S2D), SIOS Datakeeper, or Amazon FSx.

Amazon provides a very though [overview](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/microsoft-sql-fci-fsx/) and [deployment guide](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-microsoft-sql-fci-fsx/) for installing SQL Server FCIs using Amazon FSx. It is a comparatively complex configuration, compared to building standalone instances, or even Availability Groups.

Note that Amazon's recommendations in the [deployment guide](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-microsoft-sql-fci-fsx/) do not use AMIs with SQL Server already installed, but depend on your purchasing licensing on your own:

> This Quick Start deploys MSSQL in Bring-Your-Own-License mode. It does not support deployment of MSSQL license-included Amazon Machine Images (AMIs).

Answer (score 0):

I can launch SQL Server FCI over the existing EC2 Windows Server with SQL.
I have two node cluster (This is a limitation of Microsoft for Standard Edition).
The SQL Installation file is present in the `C:` drive of the Windows Machine.
You can use this installation file and launch more SQL Server Instances.